# Is it possible to authenticate users offline when using firebase?

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication

I am trying to find a way to work offline with Firebase. But I've noticed that I need to be online to authenticate the user and then sync data to firebase, holding events to fire when the app gets back online when in an intermittent conection. But it is not what I need. My app should work like this:

When the user is offline and have not been logged in previously, he needs to log in in some way and also be able to create a report that will be send to the cloud when he is back online. Even if he can't log in offline, it can also work if the firebase send the report created offline automatically when the user log in again.

Is there anyway to contour this issue? Is there any database that can contour this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication requires that a trusted entity (i.e. server hardware controlled by some authentication provider) verify the credentials that the user provides against the credentials that are stored for this user. That is not possible when the user is offline.

What you *can* do is assume that the user's authentication will succeed, and prepare the report while they're offline. Then, when the user comes back online, you can finish the authentication and send the report. This is essentially how the Firebase Realtime Database, and Cloud Firestore, handle writes that happen on the device while the user is offline.